# biblatex undefined control sequence error at \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am new to biblatex and I receive the following error when compiling the below code:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\namepartfamily ->\x
{fffd}\x {fffd}str\x {fffd}\x {fffd}m
l.16
```

tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{aaa.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{aaa}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

bib file

```
@InProceedings{aaa,
  author    = {aaa},
  title     = {aaa},
  booktitle = {aaa},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {ACM},
  date      = {1977},
  type      = {Conference Proceedings},
}
```

compilation
pdflatex 
bib(la)tex
pdflatex

Comment: Your backend is `biber`, you should compile with `pdflatex > biber > pdflatex > pdflatex`.

Comment: I get no error. Please, add the real bib entry that produces the issue.

Comment: yes I'm using this compilation and yet giving the error

Comment: even with this entry I'm getting the error

Comment: Normally an error like this appears if you are using a non-ASCII character and your encodings don't match. In your document you requested `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, so you need to make sure both the `.bib` and `.tex` file are encoded in UTF-8. Your example should not show this error because it only contains ASCII characters. You could still see the error, however, due to the fact that some temporary files (especially `.bbl`, but also `.aux`, `.blg`) contain outdated information. Try your example again in an empty directory and report back.

Comment: Does that mean that your problem is fixed? If so you might want to contribute an answer so we can mark this question as solved. If you think that one of the commenters gave the answer in the comments, ask them to convert their comment into a proper answer.

Comment: @moewe Very correct observation. In my case the error message was thrown because of ä not coded as `\"{a}` in the bib file. As far as I am concerned, your comment is the answer to the post problem.

Comment: @XavierStuvw If the encoding of the `.tex` and `.bib` file match and is correctly set in the `.tex` file (ideally you'd use UTF-8), `ä` should work like a charm.